# Matlab - Importing a .dat file into an array

Tags: arrays, matlab, import

I'm still fairly new to Matlab but for some reason the documentation hasn't been all that helpful with this.

I've got a `.dat` file that I want to turn into a `_` row by 6 column array (the number of rows changes depending on the program that's generating the `.dat` file). What I need to do is get the dimensions of the image this array will be used to make from the 1st row 2nd column (`x` dimension) and 1st row 4th column (`y` dimension). When using the Import Data tool in Matlab, this works properly:

[image]

However I need the program to do it automatically. If the first line wasn't there, I'm pretty sure I could just use `fscanf` to put the data in the array, but the image dimensions are necessary.

Any idea what I need to use instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `textscan`. The first call to this function will handle the first line (i.e. get the dimension of your file) and the second call the remaining of your file. The second call uses `repmat` to declare the format spec: `%f`, meaning `double`, repeated `nb_col` times. The option `CollectOutput` will concatenate all the columns in a single array. Note that `textscan` can read the entire file without specifying the number of rows.

The code would be

```
fileID = fopen('youfile.dat');     %declare a file id

C1 = textscan(fileID,'%s%f%s%f');   %read the first line
nb_col = C1{4};                     %get the number of columns (could be set by user too) 

%read the remaining of the file
C2 = textscan(fileID, repmat('%f',1,nb_col), 'CollectOutput',1);

fclose(fileID);                     %close the connection
```

---

In the case where the the number of columns is fixed, you can simply do

```
fileID = fopen('youfile.dat');
C1 = textscan(fileID,'%s%f%s%f');   %read the first line
im_x = C1{2};                       %get the x dimension 
im_y = C1{4};                       %get the x dimension 

C2 = textscan(fileID,'%f%f%f%f%f%f%*[^\n]', 'CollectOutput',1);
fclose(fileID);
```

The format specification `%*[^\n]` skips the remaining of a line.

Comment: Sorry, I might have been unclear. The array I need to create isn't 200x341, that's the dimension of the image that this will be used to create. What I need to do is get the image dimensions out of that first line and then turn the rest of that .dat file into the array I need, in this case going from a 68201x6 array to a 68200x6 array. AT the moment, when I try to get the dimensions of the image from the code you posted, all I get is: Nx = 

    [136401x1 double]


Ny = 

    [136401x1 double]